# excel conditional formatting cell if separate worksheet contains matching cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements

TLDR: I'm having trouble trying to get a conditional formatting formula to work that goes over an area and checks to see if any cell's value in that area matches a value in a cell in another sheet then formats that specific cell(s) accordingly

Hello everyone,
I'm trying to make a relatively advanced (at least for me) conditional formatting formula but I cannot seem to get it to work, all the components work individually but if I try to add them together I run into formula errors and it stops working altogether.

What I'm trying to do:
I have a map of all the rooms I have on the property I work at and every time someone checks in/out/or transfers units I have to update a map. I can do this pretty comfortably but some of my coworkers have issues so I'm trying to make this to simplify their jobs.
The map looks like this

```
|     |     |     |     |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 201 | 101 |
| 102 | 202 | 203 | 103 |
|etc  |etc  |etc  |etc  |
```

I can have a report generated and automatically added to the spreadsheet and have set that up and if i check a single cell for a value the formula works, but if i check an area of cells it stops working
e.g. `=C8='down rooms'!$A$28`works
`=C8:BB43='down rooms'!$A2:$A200`does not work (and formats half of my blank cells but not the other half of blank cells and nothing else)
if i were to break down all i need into components im looking at something like this:

`=C8:BB43='down rooms'!$A2:$A200` *C8:BB43 my property map, go over and check down rooms sheet for units listed*

`=right(*,3)`*remove building name from room number in down rooms sheet*

sorry if this is formatted or explained poorly, I rarely work with excel and I VERY rarely post help threads

Comment: Someone answered this and the comment was deleted (dont know if self or mod, but it worked
```=--(IFERROR(MATCH(C8,$A$2:$A$200,0),0))>0``` was the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

=--(IFERROR(MATCH(C8,'down rooms'!$A$2:$A$200,0),0))>0

Before creating the conditional format rule, select the entire area to which you want the rule to apply, then enter the above as your rule. Because C8 is not locked (i.e., it's not $C$8), the rule will be applied to other cell addresses in the selected area. The double negation (--) causes a FALSE result to become a 0. Any matched rows will be >0 and so the overall formula will return TRUE and apply your conditional format.

EDIT

To set up the conditional formatting to handle the RIGHT() text function, use:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(C8,NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT('down rooms'!$A$2:$A$200,3)),0),0)>0
```

The NUMBERVALUE() function is necessary because your "down room" values are set up as text  (e.g., E-205) and the values in C2, etc., are numbers. NUMBERVALUE converts what was text into a number (even though "205" contains numbers).

Comment: I deleted, edited, and then reposted to include the reference to the 'down rooms' sheet in the formula.

Comment: You're awesome, thank you! i had no clue about the locked cell formatting rule, i kept trying wildcards hoping something would work lol

Comment: Conditional formatting can be frustrating for a variety of reasons. Would appreciate it if you could select my response as the answer.

Comment: sorry tried that on the first one but it was already deleted then i forgot lol. you earned it boss. thank you again

Comment: Thanks. Good luck to you!

Comment: sorry to basically necro this but i tried adding right() to the formula and it no longer works (i cant figure out how to automatically format the import how it needs to be
=--(IFERROR(
    MATCH(
        C8,RIGHT('down rooms'!$B$2:$B$200,3),0),0))>0

sorry not used to stackoverflow comments didnt know i couldnt format things how i wanted to...but yeah is there a way for it to only consider the last three numbers in the down rooms?  basically it shows E-286 for a room and i need it to just show 286 for the formatting to work...

Comment: Let me see if I can get your edit to work. On the face it looks right. Need to be off line for a bit but I'll turn back to this.